# Why empty variables cause crash

Tags: windows, batch-file

Using empty variables doesn't necessarily cause a crash. But when using them inside an `IF` case will crash the program. Why? Even if `EnableDelayedExpansion` is not set here, why isn't e.g. the variable `PATHDEF` below not treated as an empty variable?

Calling the below script with input `APP` will cause a crash with different error messages. (**I.e I call the script below with an input argument which will lead to `IF` evaluating to true**)

On windows console: `\Intel\iCLS was unexpected at this time.`

On Bamboo server: `\Graphviz2.38\bin was unexpected at this time.`

```
echo off

SET app=%1
SET PATHDEF=%PATH%

echo %PATHDEF%  <--- This works. Prints path

echo %THIS%     <--- This works. Prints "ECHO is off" (since %THIS% is empty)

IF %app%==APP (
    echo %PATHDEF%  <--- This causes crash!
)
```

Comment: `app` appears to be empty (you do not provide an argument for the batch file, do you?), hence `IF %app%==APP` expands to `IF ==APP`, which is invalid syntax; note that immediate (`%`) expansion takes place *before* execution, and delayed (`!`) expansion is done *during* execution, that is why it works with the latter...

Comment: @aschipfl Yes I do provide an input argument as stated in the question. I call the script with input `APP` so the `IF` evaluates to true.

Comment: Best practice is to always use quotes around string comparisons. `IF "%app%"=="APP"`

Comment: Your question contradicts itself. Your title is about empty variables, but the body of your question claims all variables have values. So which is it? Slow down, and be more precise with your question. I suspect you actually have two different questions, with answers that are unrelated to each other.

Comment: @dbenham I was convinced that it broke because variable was considered empty inside `IF`. But you are right, I was stressed and this bugged the f out of me. I'm slowing down next time. Tnx. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of the unescaped close parenthesis in %PATH%. The first item in your PATH variable is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\`.

Variables are expanded at runtime, so

```
IF %app%==APP (
    echo %PATHDEF%
)
```

is actually being read as

```
IF %app%==APP (
    echo C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;
)
```

Because of how the cmd interpreter parses parentheses, it decides that the first unquoted, unescaped close parentheses is the end of the code block, so your code is being treated like you wrote

```
IF %app%==APP (
    echo C:\Program Files (x86
)
\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;
```

And since things outside of code blocks get processed first, the script recognizes that `\Intel\iCLS` is not a valid command, so it throws an error there instead of echoing `C:\Program Files (x86`.

---

There are two ways to avoid this:

**OPTION ONE - Put the variable in quotes**

```
IF %app%==APP (
    echo "%PATHDEF%"
)
```

Unfortunately, this means the quotes get included when being displayed.

**OPTION TWO - Put everything on the same line**

`IF %app%==APP echo %PATHDEF%`

With no opening parenthesis to mess everything up, the contents will print correctly without the need to quote or escape anything.

Comment: omg... Of course. Well spotted! Dont know why I didn't see that one. I was conviced it had to do with delayed expansions and that the Intel-thing was a CPU error. Actually it's not my first item, it's far down the path string but that is the first occurence of `(x86)`. Thanks!